# C# behaving abnormally in checking for conditions

Tags: c#, if-statement, entity-framework-6

[image]

rule value:
[image]

Can any one help me understand how the control is moving into the 'if' block even if rule variable is not null? I'm using EF6

Thanks!

Comment: Can you hover over the rule value itself?

Comment: if you put the `rule` into the watches window, what value does `rule` contains?

Comment: I see that the type is a dynamic proxy from EF, could that be part of the bug (lazy-loading or something)

Comment: Before chalking this up to a debugger bug, are you sure this isn't an issue related to debugging code that multiple threads are hitting?

Comment: Do you have this setting checked?  `Debug (menu) -> Options (menu item) -> Debugging (tab) -> General -> "Require source files to exactly match the original version"`    If not it can cause issues like this where you think code should be doing one thing but is actually doing another because the compiled version is out of date/does not match your `.cs` file(s).

Comment: @hatchet - not a bad idea. If you look at the variable `rule` in screenshot #1 it is created in that method so has no class/external scope. I believe it would not be possible for a different thread to change the pointer to an object.

Comment: Did all that. But seems to be a genuine bug in c#

Answer (score 4):

This is a debugger bug. The behavior that is evident in the screenshot is impossible under the C# language spec.

This could be a CLR bug but that is highly unlikely. `if` does not have bugs.

Create a small, executable repro and report it on MS Connect.

You can add an assertion `rule == null` in the `if` statement body and it will not fire. That proves that the value is actually `null` as expected.

As a funny yet unlikely alternative theory there could be an overloaded and broken operator equals.

In my experience debugger bugs are not rare. I have found a few over the years. Nothing too serious. The debugger is a very complicated piece of machinery that inspects running programs in a very invasive way. Hard to get that 100% right.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation (outside of an unlikely bug in VS) is that the source version does not match the compiled version (compiled version = debug symbols). This is possible using this setting in Visual Studio.

> Debug (menu) -> Options (menu item) -> Debugging (tab) -> General -> "Require source files to exactly match the original version"

If you had `if(rule != null)` before and all you did was change it to `if(rule == null)` in the code but the debug symbols did not update then this could explain the behavior on screen.

Comment: That's plausible as well.